# VB.net, SQL 2012, selecting phone data where date is today

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm making a wallboard app that displays all call records from a database in SQL 2012 server. I've been trying stuff left and right but everything gives one of 2 errors executing the select command:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string"

or

> "Invalid column name '07/07/2017 15:03:35'."

Here is an SQL select command example i have:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > """ & DateToday & """"
```

I've worked on a different wallboard program for the company i'm on and when I tried retrieving data from the current date it worked with the select command above (tweaked obviously) and only with this has it started having problems on me.

edit: oops, where it says DateToday i mean DateYesterday, my bad

edit*: This is the code im using to essentially count the number of calls that happened today, it might be rubbish, but it was from the person who was here before me had this and when i was told to continue his work I just used and improvised his code since it was working and the databases i've worked with are all similar if not the same

```
SDACallsP = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdCallsP, conn)
Dim num_calls_parceiros = SDACallsP.Fill(data_set, "dbo.tblCallList")
cs_parceiros.Text = num_calls_parceiros


cmdCallsP = String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > ''" & DateYesterday & "''")
Dim DateYesterday As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Change the double quotes to 2 single quotes.

Comment: It threw an exception, "Incorrect syntax near '07' " (07 is today's day), i've also tried adding a single quote before and after the variable's double quotes

Comment: Can you show the code snippet? And does this work in SSMS?

Comment: I think It works in SSMS because there are premade functions from the phone maker (Avaya) to get the data from x day to y day and I don't know or think there is a way to call them in vb .net, i'll put the code in the question.

Comment: Could you use `getDate()` instead to return the date/time?

Comment: Always use SQL parameters.  They prevent this sort of thing and many other disasters

Comment: Thanks but i've tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Plutonix yeah, i need to revamp this code i've been recycling for a while now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the use of double quotes ("). In SQL Server you should use single quote (')

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > '" & DateToday & "'"
```

However, you shouldn't be querying by a date with time. May be the best solution for you is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > cast('" & DateToday & "' as date)"
```

Comment: Using this didn't throw any exception anymore but doesn't seem to retrieve anything either as it shows 0 on the label that displays the number of calls  in
edit: Nevermind, still an exception, starting to think i should rework the code.

Comment: That's a date problem. The cast should help, however, you may check how the dates are stored in your database. You can use SQL Server profiler to check how the select is arriving in sql server, it will help

Comment: 'Incorrect syntax near '06/06/2017 00:00:00'.'  ; The dates in the database are displayed like this "2017-06-06 15:30:51.000"

Comment: This is the correct statement, with no syntax error: SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE 
CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > cast( '06/06/2017 00:00:00' as date)  . Check if your code is building this statement correctly.

You can also change the date order:

SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE 
CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > cast( '2017/06/06 00:00:00' as date) 

If you send this statement to sql server, it will work.

Comment: I put that directly in the program and it seems to have counted them, that's a start i guess, although it seems to have counted way too many (4000 is too many?)

Comment: The problem now seems to be that its grabbing data from last month instead of last day, have tried moving the order on the Date variable

Comment: Althought i am stuck with a lesser issue, this answer did solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
cmdCallsP = String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE CategoryId = 1 AND CreateDate > '" & DateYesterday.ToString & "'")

I do not think you need the double single quotes

Comment: Threw this exception "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" , now this one is a weird one...

Comment: You probably have a problem with the date format of the client and the server. If you use a command object with a parameter, it may work.

Comment: I remember trying that but i vaguely remember, it might just be my code that is really bad for this project but i have tried so many and none worked that i undid everything to when it at least pulled ALL the records from the database, which are 1 million + calls... The dates in the database are displayed like this "2017-06-06 15:30:51.000"